# When $H^{p,q}_{\bar\partial}(X)$ can be seen as a subspace of $H^k(X,\mathbb C)$?

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-manifolds

It is known that for a $\partial\bar\partial$-manifold $X$ (a compact complex manifold satisfies the $\partial\bar\partial$-lemma), the Bott-Chern cohomology $H_{BC}^{\bullet,\bullet}:=\frac{\ker \partial\cap\ker\bar\partial}{\text{im }\partial\bar\partial}$ is isomorphic to the Dolbeault cohomology $H_{\bar\partial}^{\bullet,\bullet}(X)=\frac{\ker\bar\partial}{\text{im }\bar\partial}$, and the Frölicher spectral sequence of $X$ degenerates at $E_1$, then
$$
H^k(X,\mathbb C)=\bigoplus_{p+q=k}H^{p,q}_{\bar\partial}(X)=\bigoplus_{p+q=k}H^{p,q}_{BC}(X),
$$
so $H^{p,q}_{\bar\partial}(X)$ can be treated as a subspace of $H^k(X,\mathbb C)$ through the isomorphism between Bott-Chern and Dolbeault cohomology.

If we only assume that the Frölicher spectral sequence of $X$ degenerates at $E_1$, is there a natural way to treat $H^{p,q}_{\bar\partial}(X)$ as a subspace of $H^k(X,\mathbb C)$? or is there a natural map $f:H^{p,q}_{\bar\partial}(X)\to H^k(X,\mathbb C)$ which is injective?

Comment: Every surface has Fr\"olicher spectral sequence degenerating at $E_1$, so there is probably no chance to have any natural map

Comment: Noncanonically, though, one can perform the following: choose a splitting of the cohomology of the $\bar\partial$ operator. That is, pick a representative for any $\bar\partial$-cohomology class, choose the complement of the space of the representatives inside all forms and choose an operator $h$ of degree $-1$ such that $\mathrm{Id} - \partial h - h\partial$
is the corresponding projection onto $\bar\partial$-cohomology. Then, if $\alpha$ is a $\bar\partial$-closed $(p,q)$-form, the form $\sum_{n \ge 0}(h\partial)^n\alpha$ will be $d$-closed and non-exact if FSS degenerates at $E_1$.

Comment: This follows, for example, from the Khovanov's classification of bicomplexes into zig-zags: https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.02503.
The Fr\"olicher spectral sequence degenerates at $E_1$ if and only if there are no zig-zags of odd length in the corresponding bicomplex.

Comment: sorry, it should read "if $\alpha$ is a $\bar\partial$-closed and not $\bar\partial$-exact $(p,q)$-form..."

Comment: @GrishaPapayanov, your construction of $\mathrm{Id} - \partial h - h\partial$ seems very unnatural, I don't why we should care about this kind of operator.

Comment: Suppose we want to construct a map $H_{\bar\partial}\to H_{dR}$ by assigning a $d$-closed representative to each class $\alpha\in H_{\bar\partial}$. We can do this for each $\alpha$ separately $\Longleftrightarrow$ $\partial(\ker\bar\partial)\subset\operatorname{im}\partial\bar\partial$. This condition implies $E_1=E_\infty$ (for example, it implies $\partial(\ker\bar\partial)\subset\operatorname{im}\bar\partial$, which means $E_1=E_2$). Does the reverse implication hold?

Comment: @igorf, why "we can do this for each $\alpha$ separately $\iff \partial(\ker \bar\partial)\subset \text{im }\partial\bar\partial$"? For $\alpha\in A^{p,q}\cap \ker \bar\partial$, we should find a $d$-closed $(p+q)$-form $\beta$, but the question is how to relate them?

Comment: Suppose $\bar\partial\alpha=0$, we want to find $\beta$ such that $0=d(\alpha-\bar\partial\beta)=\partial\alpha-\partial\bar\partial\beta$, that is, $\partial\alpha=\partial\bar\partial\beta$. Such $\beta$ exists for each $\alpha\in\ker\bar\partial$ iff $\partial(\ker\bar\partial)$ is in the image of $\partial\bar\partial$.

Comment: @igorf, thanks, it is clear now, but for the reverse implication, do we have $E_1=E_2$ implies $\partial(\ker\bar\partial)\subset\operatorname{im}\bar\partial$, thus $\bar\partial$-closed form $\alpha$ can always be represented by a closed form?

Comment: Yes, $E_1=E_2$ is equivalent to $\partial(\ker\bar\partial)\subset\operatorname{im}\bar\partial$, because $d_1[\alpha]=[\partial\alpha]$.

Comment: So, there are implications $\partial(\ker\bar\partial)\subset\operatorname{im}\partial\bar\partial$ $\Longrightarrow$ $E_1=E_\infty$ (degeneration of the Frölicher spectral sequence at $E_1$) $\Longrightarrow$ $E_1=E_2$. The second implication is not an equivalence (a counterexample can be found in Cordero, Fernandez, Ugarte, Gray, Frölicher Spectral Sequence of Compact Nilmanifolds with Nilpotent Complex Structure, 1999). I don't know about the first one, but I'd bet it is not an equivalence either.

Comment: @igorf, maybe I have misunderstood your explanation, but $\partial(\ker\bar\partial)\subset\operatorname{im}\bar\partial$ does not imply $\bar\partial$-closed $(p,q)$-form $\alpha$ can be represented by a $d$-closed form, which is equivalent to $\partial(\ker \bar\partial)\subset \text{im }\partial\bar\partial$?

Comment: Yes, I think you got it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that the following answers the question, but at least it shows that it is not always possible to construct a map $H_{\bar\partial}\to H_{dR}$ by assigning a $d$-closed representative to each class in $H_{\bar\partial}$.

Suppose $\alpha$ is a $\bar\partial$-closed form, and we want to find $\beta$ such that $d(\alpha-\bar\partial\beta)=0$. Each summand inside the parentheses is $\bar\partial$-closed, so the equality is equivalent to $\partial\alpha=\partial\bar\partial\beta$. We learn that each class in $H_{\bar\partial}$ admits a $d$-closed representative if and only if $\partial\ker\bar\partial\subset\operatorname{im}\partial\bar\partial$ — in a more fancy language, the map $H_{\bar\partial}\to H_{BC}$ induced by $\partial$ is zero.

As explained in [Ornea, Verbitsky, Vuletescu, Classification of non-Kähler surfaces and locally conformally Kähler geometry](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.05768), § 2.2, for any non-Kähler compact complex surface, the image of $H^{0,1}_{\bar\partial}$ by this map is 1-dimensional. So there is a class in $H^{0,1}_{\bar\partial}$ with no $d$-closed representative, notwithstanding that the Frölicher spectral sequence of any compact complex surface degenerates at the first page.